# EntityManagerFactory closed after context reloaded with @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app which uses JMS to connect to a queue and listen for incoming messages.  In the app I have an integration test which sends some messages to a queue, then makes sure that the things that are supposed to happen when the listener picks up a new message actually happen.

I have annotated my test class with `@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`
  to ensure my database is clean after each test.  Each test passes when it is run in isolation. However when running them all together after the first test passes successfully the next test fails with the exception below when the code under test attempts to save an entity to the database:

```
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.handleWorkflowEvent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mottmac.processflow.infra.jms.EventListener.onWorkflowEvent(EventListener.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mottmac.processflow.infra.jms.EventListener.onMessage(EventListener.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1401) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:367) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:449) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:369) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

My test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestGovernance.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ActivitiIntegrationTest
{
    private static final String TEST_PROCESS_KEY = "oneTaskProcess";
    private static final String FIRST_TASK_KEY = "theTask";
    private static final String NEXT_TASK_KEY = "nextTask";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jms;

    @Autowired
    private WorkflowEventRepository eventRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Test
    public void workFlowEventForRunningTaskMovesItToTheNextStage() throws InterruptedException
    {
        sendMessageToCreateNewInstanceOfProcess(TEST_PROCESS_KEY);

        Task activeTask = getActiveTask();        
        assertThat(activeTask.getTaskDefinitionKey(), is(FIRST_TASK_KEY));

        sendMessageToUpdateExistingTask(activeTask.getProcessInstanceId(), FIRST_TASK_KEY);

        Task nextTask = getActiveTask();        
        assertThat(nextTask.getTaskDefinitionKey(), is(NEXT_TASK_KEY));
    }

    @Test
    public void newWorkflowEventIsSavedToDatabaseAndKicksOffTask() throws InterruptedException
    {
        sendMessageToCreateNewInstanceOfProcess(TEST_PROCESS_KEY);

        assertThat(eventRepository.findAll(), hasSize(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void newWorkflowEventKicksOffTask() throws InterruptedException
    {
        sendMessageToCreateNewInstanceOfProcess(TEST_PROCESS_KEY);

        Task activeTask = getActiveTask();        
        assertThat(activeTask.getTaskDefinitionKey(), is(FIRST_TASK_KEY));
    }


    private void sendMessageToUpdateExistingTask(String processId, String event) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WorkflowEvent message = new WorkflowEvent();
        message.setRaisedDt(ZonedDateTime.now());
        message.setEvent(event);
        // Existing
        message.setIdWorkflowInstance(processId);
        jms.convertAndSend("workflow", message);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    private void sendMessageToCreateNewInstanceOfProcess(String event) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WorkflowEvent message = new WorkflowEvent();
        message.setRaisedDt(ZonedDateTime.now());
        message.setEvent(event);
        jms.convertAndSend("workflow", message);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    private Task getActiveTask()
    {
        // For some reason the tasks in the task service are hanging around even
        // though the context is being reloaded. This means we have to get the
        // ID of the only task in the database (since it has been cleaned
        // properly) and use it to look up the task.
        WorkflowEvent workflowEvent = eventRepository.findAll().get(0);
        Task activeTask = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(workflowEvent.getIdWorkflowInstance().toString()).singleResult();
        return activeTask;
    }

}
```

The method that throws the exception in the application (`repository` is just a standard Spring Data `CrudRepository`):

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void handleWorkflowEvent(WorkflowEvent event)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.info("Handling workflow event[{}]", event);

            // Exception is thrown here:
            repository.save(event);

            logger.info("Saved event to the database [{}]", event);
            if(event.getIdWorkflowInstance() == null)
            {
                String newWorkflow = engine.newWorkflow(event.getEvent(), event.getVariables());
                event.setIdWorkflowInstance(newWorkflow);
            }
            else 
            {
                engine.moveToNextStage(event.getIdWorkflowInstance(), event.getEvent(), event.getVariables());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error while handling workflow event:" , e);
        }
    }
```

My test configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@TestConfiguration
public class TestGovernance
{
    private static final String WORKFLOW_QUEUE_NAME = "workflow";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
    {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public EventListenerJmsConnection connection(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws NamingException, JMSException
    {
        // Look up ConnectionFactory and Queue
        Destination destination = new ActiveMQQueue(WORKFLOW_QUEUE_NAME);

        // Create Connection
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        Session listenerSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageConsumer receiver = listenerSession.createConsumer(destination);

        EventListenerJmsConnection eventListenerConfig = new EventListenerJmsConnection(receiver, connection);
        return eventListenerConfig;
    }
}
```

The JMS message listener (not sure if that will help):

```
/**
 * Provides an endpoint which will listen for new JMS messages carrying
 * {@link WorkflowEvent} objects.
 */
@Service
public class EventListener implements MessageListener
{
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventListener.class);

    private WorkflowEventHandler eventHandler;

    private MessageConverter messageConverter;

    private EventListenerJmsConnection listenerConnection;

    @Autowired
    public EventListener(EventListenerJmsConnection listenerConnection, WorkflowEventHandler eventHandler, MessageConverter messageConverter)
    {
        this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
        this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
        this.listenerConnection = listenerConnection;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUpConnection() throws NamingException, JMSException
    {
        listenerConnection.setMessageListener(this);
        listenerConnection.start();
    }

    private void onWorkflowEvent(WorkflowEvent event)
    {
        logger.info("Recieved new workflow event [{}]", event);
        eventHandler.handleWorkflowEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            message.acknowledge();
            WorkflowEvent fromMessage = (WorkflowEvent) messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
            onWorkflowEvent((WorkflowEvent) fromMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `@Transactional' to the test methods and removing it from the code under test and various combinations with no success. I've also tried adding various test execution listeners and I still can't get it to work. If I remove the`@DirtiesContext` then the exception goes away and all the tests run without exception (they do however fail with assertion errors as I would expect).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My searches so far haven't turned up anything, everything suggests that `@DirtiesContext` should work.

Comment: Which is a very bad reason to use dirties context. Don't do that it is slow and when your test suite grows and the number of beans it will be even slower. So don't. Make your test `@Transactional` and the default is that data will be rolled back after your test. They might fail as there is nothing committed so you might need/want to inject the `EntityManager` and put a `entityManager.flush()` in between method calls to simulate a commit. You are even using a SpringBootTest (just noticed) which makes it probably an even more terrible idea to restart your whole application for the test.

Comment: In additional I would say your JMS setup is flawed and you can make it a whole lot easier. By just implementing your `onMessage` with `@JmsLIstener` and some queue names in there spring will do the rest.

Comment: I did originally have `@JmsListener` but something about the way the the auto configuration sets it up meant that it wouldn't work in production when combined with a Microsoft Service Bus.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@DirtiesContext` for this is a terrible idea (imho) what you should do is make your tests `@Transactional`. I would also suggest to remove the `Thread.sleep` and use something like [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) instead.

In theory when you execute a query all pending changes should be committed so you could use awaitility to check for at most 6 seconds to see if something has been persisted in the database. If that doesn't work you can try adding a flush before the query.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestGovernance.class })
@Transactional
public class ActivitiIntegrationTest {

    private static final String TEST_PROCESS_KEY = "oneTaskProcess";
    private static final String FIRST_TASK_KEY = "theTask";
    private static final String NEXT_TASK_KEY = "nextTask";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jms;

    @Autowired
    private WorkflowEventRepository eventRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void workFlowEventForRunningTaskMovesItToTheNextStage() throws InterruptedException
    {
        sendMessageToCreateNewInstanceOfProcess(TEST_PROCESS_KEY);

        await().atMost(6, SECONDS).until(getActiveTask() != null);

        Task activeTask = getActiveTask());
        assertThat(activeTask.getTaskDefinitionKey(), is(FIRST_TASK_KEY));

        sendMessageToUpdateExistingTask(activeTask.getProcessInstanceId(), FIRST_TASK_KEY);

        Task nextTask = getActiveTask();        
        assertThat(nextTask.getTaskDefinitionKey(), is(NEXT_TASK_KEY));
    }

    private Task getActiveTask()
    {
        em.flush(); // simulate a commit
        // For some reason the tasks in the task service are hanging around even
        // though the context is being reloaded. This means we have to get the
        // ID of the only task in the database (since it has been cleaned
        // properly) and use it to look up the task.
        WorkflowEvent workflowEvent = eventRepository.findAll().get(0);
        Task activeTask = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(workflowEvent.getIdWorkflowInstance().toString()).singleResult();
        return activeTask;
    }

}
```

You might need / want to polish your `getActiveTask` a little to be able to `return null` or maybe this change makes it even behave like you expected it to do.

I just did a single method the others you can probably figure out yourself. Your gain with this approach is probably 2 fold, 1 it will not wait for 5 seconds anymore but less and you don't have to reload your whole application between tests. Both of which should make your tests faster.

Comment: I've updated the tests to use `@Transactional` but it doesn't seem to be cleaning out the database.  I can see in the debug log that it's doing something: `2017-03-16 19:24:11.216 DEBUG 12348 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@18c820d2]`  but when I run all the tests together it gets to the last test method and there are 4 items in the database. The test passes in isolation so I know it's definitely not the test that's putting them all in the database.

Comment: I'm looking at the logs and wondering if the fact that the code under test is running in a different thread has anything to do with it. The JMS message processing is operating on thread `[Session Task-1]` and the tests are running in thread `[main]`. Everything does appear to be happening in the correct order though.

Comment: That is indeed what is happening, as transactions (and the associated `EntityManager`) are thread based that isn't going to work. Which of course is the whole idea of JMS :). I'll remove the answer as it doesn't make sense in this regard (forgot about the fact you are actually using JMS in your tests). Nonetheless I still would suggest the use of **awaitility**.

Comment: I've switched to awaitiliy now. I've used it on other projects before, the Thread::sleep was just a quick and dirty fix until I could figure out what was going wrong. I'm guessing the only solution left is to manually clear out the database after each test?

Comment: Guess that is the fastest if you really want to nuke everything you can truncate all tables (which should be pretty fast).

Comment: Sticking in `eventRepository.deleteAll();` in an `@After` block seems to do the trick.

Comment: Any good resources for why the @Transactional is better than regenerating an persistance layer via dirty context?

I mean the documentation for dirtiesContext specifically mentions to use this for embedded databases.